# Forms in Material-UI, Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to build a Registration Form using Material-UI and Reactjs.

In my code, the input validation and `required` attribute seems to be not working for a `<TextField />` component of Material-UI.

With a normal `<input />` component, the validation is happening (see below pictures).

You can find my code in this sandbox:

[image: Edit purple-wave-0rx9o]

---

[image: input validation 1]

[image: input validation 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `button` should have a `type="submit"` attribute to specify that you are doing a form submission on the click of the button. In material-ui by default `type="button"`. So you need to specify the type of the button to make it work. I have fixed it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-hamilton-694is?fontsize=14)